# It's better to add jar in new module or in libs folder in Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio, gradle

What's the best practice to add a jar file in your project application on Android Studio?

For example we will use `gson-2.3.1.jar`.

**1) With Module**

[image: New jar module capture]

And add in your build.gradle in your main module :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(":gson-2.3.1")
}
```

**2) With Libs Folder**

- Put the Gson jar (in my case, `gson-2.3.1.jar`) into the `libs` folder
- And add in your build.gradle in your main module :
  `compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')` or `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: primarily opinion-based ... anyway ... i vote for  `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'` and let the maven plugin do the rest ... obviously, if library is not available in maven repo then you have to use libs folder ... anyway please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the best way is to use the maven dependency

Add this line in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

If you would like to work with a jar, add the jar file in the libs folder and use:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: If one is not using maven, then why not via Module (as against in libs dir)?

Comment: Via Module you have to compile the code (with its dependencies). I think it is not the quickest way